# Why does this JavaScript function only work once?

Tags: javascript

I have tried hard to find out why this function only runs once, but none of the solutions seem to apply (e.g. declaring a variable the same name as a function). The following function "scroll()" scrolls my page at the required speed to coordinate with the audio reading being played. It works great, but only works once without doing a page refresh.

Where am I going wrong?

```
function scroll() {
  var element = document.getElementById("scrolldiv");
  var scrollingheight = element.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var thirdscreen = (window.innerHeight * .31);
  var halfscreen = (window.innerHeight * .69);
  var delaypercent = (thirdscreen / element.scrollHeight) * 100;
  var speedpercent = (halfscreen / element.scrollHeight) * 100;
  var dur = $("#jquery_jplayer_audio_1").data("jPlayer").status.duration;
  var speedcalc1 = (dur * speedpercent) / 100;
  var speedcalc2 = dur - speedcalc1;
  var speed = (speedcalc2 * 1000) / scrollingheight;
  speed2 = (Math.round(speed * 4) / 4).toFixed(2);
  var delay = (delaypercent * dur) * 10;
  setTimeout(function(){
      scrollinterval = setInterval("scrollmove()", speed2);
  }, delay);
}

function scrollmove() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("scrolling") == 'on') {
    var position = $('#scrolldiv').scrollTop();
    $('#scrolldiv').scrollTop(position + 1);
  }
}
```

I realize my code could be written more elegantly, but for now I am wrestling with getting it working. Thanks for any input

Comment: You never change your localStorage variable... also, why on earth would you use localStorage to determine if you're scrolling or not?  Just use a regular JS variable and complete the scroll.  Or even better, use a CSS scroll :)

Comment: Is the local storage variable a ScrollingAllowed setting?  If so, get it once rather than with each invocation of scrollmove().

Comment: The localstorage variable is set using another function. This is a phonegap app, and the localstorage preserves the scrolling on/off selection between uses. Thanks

Comment: I think the localstorage factor is not an issue...but I will remove that and try it.

Comment: Get it in scroll() and do the if (scrolling) test there.

Comment: I removed the whole localstorage "if" statement and the problem remains the same.

Comment: @Tim... I see your point though about moving the if statement to the scoll function so as to only get it once. Very good.

Comment: You never stop your `setInterval()`.

Comment: I use a function on the stop, pause and next button to clear the setInterval(), so that is covered. The problem is that it will not restart after that.

Comment: It's not causing your issue, but it's generally best practice to use a function expression rather than a string when calling `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. In this case, you can just use `setInterval(scrollmove, speed2)`.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That will help tidying this up and improving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know setTimeout() will only execute one time, and setInterval() repeats.  When you invoke either of these methods, you're creating a variable object that contains the associated callback.  When that object is dropped -- setTimeout() exectutes or setInterval() is canceled using clearInterval() -- the object gets nullified and garbage collected.  When that happens, the callback it contained and all its variables are zapped too.

Because you're nesting the setInterval() as part of a callback in a setTimeout(), your setInterval() is dropped once the setTimeout() executes.  You need to find another way to invoke setInterval();

Comment: Thanks Sean. I have used the SetTimeout to allow me to delay the scrolling until the reader has read halfway down the window... I will try to figure it another way.

Comment: Just a thought, why does setTimeout() not start over again when scroll() is called again?

Comment: I can't say.  You're event handler code isn't shown.  Check by setting a break point with Chrome dev tools and watch your call stack.